# Can I use CSS functions in Vue.js bind inline styles? Vue.js assumes translate3d() is meant to be a JavaScript function and says it's not defined

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to do the following thing:

```
<img v-bind:style="{ transform: translate3d(50 + 'px', 50 + 'px', 50 + 'px') }" src="#">
```

But I get the error `Property or method "translate3d" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render.`

I understand why am I getting the error, it's because Vue.js assumed translate3d is a JavaScript function but since such function is not defined, it throws the error. What I can't figure out is how to use a CSS function in the bind inline styles?

Comment: Why do you need to bind at all? You're not doing anything dynamic; you're just trying to hard-code an inline style. So just replace the whole thing with a traditional `style=` attribute.

Comment: Well the pixels are gonna be dynamic, I'm just using hard coded values to test right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When binding inline styles with Vue, the syntax is this:

```
v-bind:style='{cssProperty: valueSource}'
```

...where `valueSource` is a Vue property, method or computed that returns the value to be applied to the CSS property `cssProperty`.

You're not using it like that; you're using the second half of the equation to pass your literal CSS value, which is not what Vue expects.

You clarify in the comments that you wish to make *part* of the value dynamic - the pixel values - but this won't be possible with a binding. Instead, use a method, where you can compute the pixel values, build the string, and then return it to have Vue apply it.

HTML:

```
<img v-bind:style="{transform: getTransform()}" src="#">
```

JS:

```
...
methods: {
    getTransform() {
        //build string here
        let str = "translate3d(50 + 'px', 50 + 'px', 50 + 'px')";
        return str;
    }
}
...
```